# listeners on Java

Tags: java, listener

Could anybody explain what's the problem with listeners in this code?

I just started learning how listeners work and don't really realize how the `ChangeListener` works.

```
import java.awt.event.*;

class Button2 implements ChangeListener { //what's whong here

  public void changePerformed(ChangeEvent s) { //and here?
    System.out.println("Pressed the button " + s.getChangeCommand());
  }
}
```

Then I add two buttons.

```
.....
but1.addChangeListener(new Button2 ());
but2.addChangeListener(new Button2 ());
.....
```

Comment: what's the error you're seeing?

Comment: To make it easier to answer your question, you should specify what you know already, e.g. compiler gives error message (and give the exact error message), or nothing happens at runtime, or teacher said it was wrong even though it works.

Comment: Which ChangeListener/ChangeEvent did you import. I have none in my java.awt.event package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChangeListener`'s required method is `stateChanged`, not `changePerformed`.

Edit: Also, as pointed out in a comment above, the `ChangeListener` I'm aware of is in `javax.swing.event`, not `java.awt.event`.

Comment: if I change the changePerformed to stateChanged the error does not dissapear.

Comment: @user693567 which error? Please describe the rror you're seeing.

Comment: eclipse writes that the error is in System.out.println("Pressed the button " + s.getChangeCommand()); line

Comment: @user693567 The javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent does not have a getChangeCommand()

Answer (score 1):

As zerocrats wrote `ChangeListener`'s method is indeed `stateChanged()` and not `changePerformed()`

In addition, `CahngeEvent` has not method called `getChangeCommand()`. If you are using regular `JButton`s and just want to catch the click on th ebuttin, why not use the good old [`ActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Pressed the button " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```